# How to add pagination in Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, mongoid, kaminari

How to add pagination to feed_entries in category?

I use kaminari, mongoid 4, rails 4

Category.rb

```
class Category
  def feed_entries
    FeedEntry.in(source_id: sources.map(&:id))
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @category.feed_entries.includes(:source).each do |feed_entry| %>
  <%= link_to feed_entry.name, feed_entry %>
  <%= feed_entry.source.title %>
<% end %>
```

Models

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_many :sources, dependent: :destroy
end

class FeedEntry
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :source, touch: true
  validates :source_id, presence: true
end

class Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  has_many :feed_entries, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

in you categories controller

```
 def show 
     @category = Category.find(params[:id]) 
     @feed_entries = @category.sources.includes(:feed_entries).page(params[:page])
 end
```

In view

```
<%= @feed_entries.each do |feed_entry| %>
  <%= link_to feed_entry.name, feed_entry %>
  <%= feed_entry.source.title %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @feed_entries %>
```

Comment: doesnt' work in category_controller.rb  **undefined method `sources' for Category:Class**

Comment: undefined method `sources' for Category:Class

Comment: Sorry category was in small, my bad. Try now

Comment: same problem **NameError (undefined local variable or method `sources' for #<CategoriesController:0x007fd2d6e8b8f8>):
  app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:11:in `show'**

Comment: undefined method `source'

Comment: In view right? but `feed_entry` should have `source`, check if feed_entry has `source_id`

Comment: doesn't work **ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<Source:0x007f8b7022deb0>):**

Comment: @AntonIpatov - Please check the value of `@feed_entries` in the view, I think it's a source object there, if so you can try something like `feed_entry.feed_entries.first.name`, `feed_entry.title` or in controller try changing `@category.feed_entries.includes(:source).page(params[:page])` with this if we get `feed_entries` object in view rather than source object

Comment: Thank you  all works with `@category.feed_entries.includes(:source).page(params[:page])` but how to add `sort_by(&:score_count).reverse` ?

Comment: `@feed_entries = @category.feed_entries.includes(:source)` `@feed_entries.sort_by! { |value| value.score_count }` `@feed_entries = @feed_entries.page(params[:page])` you can try something like this